# Redis TLS configuration with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, redis, ioredis

I'm using ioRedis node package for connecting my node js application to redis server which is secured by TLS. Redis version I'm using is Redis 6.0. My server is running fine with the certificates but while connecting from node application I get Error.

```
 Redis({
          host: "localhost",
          port: 6379,
          tls: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('./redis.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('./redis.crt'),
            maxVersion: 'TLSv1.3',
            minVersion: 'TLSv1.3',
            ca: [fs.readFileSync('./redis.pem')]
          }
        })
```

Error on the nodejs application side is

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
   Error: read ECONNRESET
            at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
```

Error on server while trying to connect from nodejs application

`17:29:44.295 # Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

Objective is just to have a redis connection with TLS security.

Comment: I am asking the same question in GitHub: https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/1076 Maybe you can comment there too.

Answer (score 23):

I was also doing the same thing and I try this approach (`node-redis` v2.8.0):

```
const redis = require('redis');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '<hostname>',
    port: <port>,
    tls: {}
});
```

Instead of passing the certificate key and everything try to pass the **tls** as an empty object.
The guide for this approach is as follow.
https://docs.upstash.com/docs/howto/connectwithtls

Comment: Updated link to docs: https://upstash.com/docs/redis/howto/connectwithtls

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify which encoding the files need to be read in

```js
const redis = require('ioredis');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = redis.createClient({
    host: 'hostName',
    port: 'port',
    tls: {
       key: fs.readFileSync('pathToFile', 'ascii')  /* this is usually the encoding */
       cert: fs.readFileSync('pathToFile', 'ascii')
       ca: fs.readFileSync('pathToFile', 'ascii')  /* this is usually the encoding */
    }

})
```

find more info [here](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_ioredis/)